# $\sum p(|S_n|\geq n\epsilon)<\infty\Leftrightarrow EX_1=0,E[X_1^2]<\infty$

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, probability-theory

$\{X_n\}$ are independent identical random variables, $S_n=X_1+...+X_n$.
Proof: for each $\epsilon>0,$
\begin{equation} 
\sum p(|S_n|\geq n\epsilon)<\infty\Leftrightarrow EX_1=0,E[X_1^2]<\infty
\end{equation}

My ideas so far:
From Borel 0-1 law:
\begin{equation} 
\sum p(|S_n|\geq n\epsilon)<\infty\Leftrightarrow p(\text{limsup}\frac{|Sn|}{n}\geq \epsilon )=0\Leftrightarrow \text{lim} \frac{|S_n|}{n}=0\Leftrightarrow\text{lim} \frac{S_n}{n}=0
\end{equation}
Also, $\sum p(|S_n|\geq n\epsilon)<\infty\Leftrightarrow E|S_n|<\infty$ (From the formula $\sum p(|S_n|\geq n)\leq E|S_n|\leq 1+\sum p(|S_n|\geq n)$), then $E|X_n|<\infty$. By strong law of large number, we have:
\begin{equation}
0=\text{lim}\frac{Sn}{n}=EX_1
\end{equation}
Which means:
$\sum p(|S_n|\geq n\epsilon)<\infty\Leftrightarrow EX_1=0$.

I don't known how to prove or use the condition $E[X_1^2]<\infty$. Are there something wrong with my proof?

Thanks in advance for any tips or help in general.

Comment: Borel-Cantelli isn't an "if and only if".

Comment: And what's your logic for concluding that $E|S_n| < \infty$?

Comment: I mean, Borel 0-1 law, which is iff.

Comment: From the formula $\sum p(|S_n|\geq n) \leq E|S_n|\leq 1+\sum p(|S_n|\geq n)$ @
Nate Eldredge

Comment: The Borel 0-1 law is for a sequence of independent events.  The random variables $S_n$ are not independent so the events $\{|S_n| \ge n \epsilon\}$ are not independent events.

Comment: The formula you are thinking of is for $\sum_n P(|X| \ge n)$, with a single random variable $X$.  You do not have that here, because the random variable $X$ is replaced by different random variables $S_n$ for different values of $n$.  Your proposed inequality doesn't even make sense because $n$ is [bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_variables_and_bound_variables) in the outer expressions, but free in $E|S_n|$.

Comment: Yes, you are right, $\{ |S_n|\geq n\}$ are not independent events now. Any suggestions to sovle this problem?

Comment: All I can think of is to use the characteristic function.  Then the sum on the left hand side becomes a rather complicated geometric series.  I couldn't finish it.

Comment: Thanks for your help!@Stephen Montgomery-Smith

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $\sum \mathbb P(|S_n|\geq n\epsilon)<\infty$ for each positive $\varepsilon$. Then $S_n/n\to 0$ almost surely, hence $X_n/n\to 0$ almost surely and it follows that $\mathbb E\left\lvert X_1\right\rvert<\infty$ and by the law of large numbers, $\mathbb E\left[X_1\right]=0$.

We use Ottaviani's inequality: if we put $M_k:=\max_{1\leqslant i\leqslant k}|S_i|$ and $S_{k,n}:=\sum_{i=k}^nX_i$, then for all $\varepsilon >0$ we have
$$\min_{1\leqslant k\leqslant n}\mathbb P(|S_{k,n}|\leqslant\varepsilon)\mathbb P(|M_n|>2\varepsilon)\leqslant \mathbb P(|S_n|>\varepsilon).$$
Using this with $\varepsilon$ replaced by $n\varepsilon$ and noticing that there exists $c>0$ and an integer $n_0$ such that
$\min_{1\leqslant k\leqslant n}\mathbb P(|S_{k,n}|\leqslant\varepsilon)>c$ for $n\geqslant n_0$, we derive that
$$\sum \mathbb P\left(\max_{1\leqslant k\leqslant n}|S_k|> n\epsilon\right)<\infty,$$
which implies that for each positive $\varepsilon$,
$$\sum \mathbb P\left(\max_{1\leqslant k\leqslant n}|X_k|> n\epsilon\right)<\infty.$$
Using Bonferroni's inequality, independence and the fact that $n\mathbb P\left(\left\lvert X_1\right\rvert>n\varepsilon\right)\to 0$, we derive that
$$\sum n\mathbb P\left(|X_1|> n\epsilon\right)<\infty,$$
giving square integrability.

For the converse, use truncation at level $n$, that is, view $S_n$ as
$S_n'+S''_n$, with
$$
S_n'=\sum_{k=1}^nX_k\mathbf{1}_{\{\lvert X_k\rvert \leqslant n\}}-\mathbb E\left[X_k\mathbf{1}_{\{\lvert X_k\rvert \leqslant n\}}\right]
$$
$$
S_n''=\sum_{k=1}^nX_k\mathbf{1}_{\{\lvert X_k\rvert \gt n\}}-\mathbb E\left[X_k\mathbf{1}_{\{\lvert X_k\rvert \gt n\}}\right].
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for you kindness help=). I learned a lot from your answer.